# Why is my typewriting component not vertically aligning?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm working on making a website portfolio and I've been using this code snippet for the typing:

```
const TypingParagraph = styled.span`
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
  margin-left: 6rem;
  color: white
  &::before {
    content: '_';
    color: transparent
  }
  &::after {
    content: '_';
    display: inline_flex;
    animation: ${rotate} 0.7s linear infinite;
  }
`;
```

For some reason though, it's not aligning vertically with its parent component. It looks like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZLlK.png) :

Also it's weird how changing the font size would also change the margins.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: Increasing the font size might be causing the element to run out of space and spill onto the next line. Why is `display: inline-flex` only on the `::after` tag? Try putting `display: flex` on the parent element. Also, when asking CSS questions show us the HTML, it helps a lot.

Comment: Yeah it got fixed after I put `display: block` for `::before`. Thanks!